Open map in the Zariski topology
I know that a quotient map of topological groups is an open map. I'm interested in the following question from algebraic geometry: Let $\pi:R\to S$ be a surjective homomorphism of commutative rings. Then it induced a continuous group homomorphism $\widetilde{\pi}:{\rm GL}_{n}(R)\to {\rm GL}_{n}(S)$ with respect to the usual Zariski topology. So, is $\widetilde{\pi}$ an open map?

@red_trumpet The determinant is a unit, so the image is a unit.

@AlexYoucis Good point!

I'm still not sure what the Zariski topology is meant to be in this case though. Say $n = 1$, you want a topology on $R^\times$? Typically the Zariski topology is defined on $\operatorname{Spec} R$, not $R$ itself?

@red_trumpet For any positive integer $n$, a subset $A\subset R^n$ is Zariski closed if there exists a family of polynomials in $R[X_1,\cdots,X_n]$ such that $A$ is the set of all common zeros for the polynomials.  Next, we can identify the  set $M_n(R)$ with $R^{n^2}$ and so define the Zariski topology on $M_n(R)$. Now, as a subgroup of $M_n(R)$, ${\rm GL}_n(R)$ is endowed with the Zariski top. induced from $M_n(R)$.

Please add the definition to the post itself, as it clarifies that you don't consider the group schemes here. The post should be self-contained. Also, please add what you have tried. Look at an example and see what is happening. You will see that this map is usually not open.
